# What is the expected length of the longest piece?

Tags: mathematics, probability

If a rod of unit length is broken into $n$ pieces, what is the expected length of the longest piece? The positions at which the rod is broken are chosen randomly uniformly.

This is a generalization of a puzzle I recently encountered, the answer to which I do not know myself:

Comment: Interesting question. I'm tempted to say $1/n$, but I have a feeling it's much more complicated than that.

Comment: @Doorknob:  it has to be greater than that: the only way the greatest is $1/n$ is if they are exactly equal.

Comment: What does "randomly uniformly" mean? How can it be both?

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat I mean chosen randomly from a [uniform distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is known as the *broken stick rule*. The [Wolfram Demonstrations Project](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/BrokenStickRule/) claims that

> If the unit interval is divided into  $n $ spaces by $ n-1$ random points, the expected size of the $i^{\text{th}}$ largest space is $$\frac 1n \sum_{j=0}^{n-i} \frac 1{n-j}$$  Setting $i=1$ gives the expected size of the largest space as $$\frac 1n H_{n-1}\approx \frac 1n(\ln(n-1)+\gamma)$$ where $H_{n-1}$ is the $n-1^{\text{st}}$ [harmonic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) and $\gamma \approx 0.5772$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).